# Angular momentum of a system when measured about two different points

Tags: angular-momentum, reference-frames

I have seen a few other questions regarding this. However, my big question is still not answered. This of course is not criticism of the other answers. It is probably my lack of understanding. I have used COM to denote centre of mass throughout my question

My question goes like this. Suppose we have a system such as the Sun-Jupiter system. I have chosen Jupiter since the Sun-Jupiter COM lies outside the sun. The Sun and Jupiter both orbit around this COM. The total angular momentum about the COM is given by:
**L** = **r**$_{Jupiter}$ $\times$ **p**$_{Jupiter}$ + **r**$_{Sun}$ $\times$ **p**$_{Sun}$, where **r**$_{Jupiter}$ and **r**$_{Sun}$ are the position vectors of Jupiter and the Sun with respect to the COM of the system.

Now, if we wanted to calculate the angular momentum about a point other than the COM but the system is still rotating about the COM how would we go about it? Would the angular momentum be the same as in the previous case? For example, if we wanted to calculate the angular momentum about the sun with the system still rotating about the COM, what adjustments would we need to make? I am quite confused about this and I am sorry if my question does not make much sense.

Comment: Are you purposefully wanting to pick a reference point that is not inertial (the sun)? Or are you just wanting to pick some other inertial point that is not the COM?

Comment: Yeah, any other inertial point that’s not the COM.